# Can bloodborne be played on ps now?

Tags: bloodborne, ps-now

I have been looking for a while now for an opening regarding Bloodborne as I am a big fan of the dark souls and demon souls series.
I have learned that PS4 games are being streamed to PS now, however I do not know if Bloodborne is as well.

Will Bloodborne be streaming to PS now as this is the only reason for me to use it for the moment. I have accepted the fact that the franchise won't come to PC soon, so I am trying to cling for a piece of hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the official Twitter](https://www.twitter.com/PlayStation/status/1036992510986514432), yes! Bloodborne is being added to PS Now in September, 2018!

Answer (score 4):

Bloodborne is coming to Playstation Plus subscribers in [March 2018](https://t.co/iO3WtKgcaN).  It is not available for PS Now streaming unfortunately.